# Code to auto-center image with in another called on page load, but not working consistently

Tags: jquery

This is a bit of an odd issue - I have some jQuery code setup to auto-vertically center a graphic within another (a banner graphic, which has a fixed height) on page load, as well as to do it again when the screen sizes changes (because the banner graphic does change height at a smaller screen size.

It does fire on page load--I setup a message to appear in the Console of Chrome's dev tools. But it doesn't always auto-vertically center the graphic within the banner. I don't see any errors in the console to indicate an issue with code, and the issue itself doesn't always occur--just sometimes.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Vertically center graphic on page load
        setPositionOfBannerText();

        //Check screensize to see if graphic needs vertically centered again
        $(window).resize(setPositionOfBannerText);

        function setPositionOfBannerText() {
            console.log("setting banner position");//this shows on in console on page load consistently
            var bannerHeight = $('.container-hero-subpage').height();
            var bannerTextHeight = $('.Banner-Text').height();
            $('.Banner-Text').css('margin-top', (bannerHeight - bannerTextHeight) / 2);
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

HTML

```
        <div class="container container-hero-subpage" style="background-image: url(pick an image)">
                <div class="subpage-banner-text-container">
                    <img class="Banner-Text" src="pick an image">
                </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.container-hero-subpage{
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1 !important;
}
.container-hero-subpage{
    height: 473px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.Banner-Text{
     z-index: 9;
     float: right;
     max-width: 100%;
     display: block;
     margin-right: 80px;
 }

//there are four graphics and four banners--the graphics aren't all the same size and they can't be changed to be all the same size
.locations-banner .Banner-Text{
    width: 500px;
}

.recipe-landing-banner .Banner-Text{
    width: 400px;
}
.categories-banner .Banner-Text{
    width: 320px;
}
.about-us-banner .Banner-Text{
    width: 500px;
}

.subpage-banner-text-container{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .categories-banner .Banner-Text,
    .recipe-landing-banner .Banner-Text{
        width: 350px;
    }
    .locations-banner .Banner-Text{
        width: 400px;
    }
    .Banner-Text{
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .about-us-banner .Banner-Text{
        width: 380px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:992px) {
    .container-hero-subpage{
        height: 360px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:576px) {
    .container-hero-subpage{
        height: 320px;
    }
}
```

Maybe the setup of the code is somehow incorrect? It looks like it makes sense and works almost all the time...

Comment: check my answer, also can you post some html so i can make a jsfiddle?

Comment: PLease provide the corresponding CSS and HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe widow resize fires too many times, try this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function ($) {
    var bannerTimeOut;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Vertically center graphic on page load
        setPositionOfBannerText();

        //Check screensize to see if graphic needs vertically centered again
        $(window).on("resize",function(){
            if(bannerTimeOut){
                // clear the timeout, if one is pending
                clearTimeout(bannerTimeOut);
                bannerTimeOut= null;
            }
            bannerTimeOut= setTimeout(setPositionOfBannerText, 250);
        });

        function setPositionOfBannerText() {
            console.log("setting banner position");//this shows on in console on page load consistently
            var bannerHeight = $('.container-hero-subpage').height();
            var bannerTextHeight = $('.Banner-Text').height();
            $('.Banner-Text').css('margin-top', (parseFloat(bannerHeight) - parseFloat(bannerTextHeight)) / 2);
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lr49d9t0/

Comment: That works ok, but when the height of the banner changes, you can easily see the graphic move to become vertically centered.  I lowered the numeric value for setTimeout to fix this.

I did catch the code not working again--I went to a page and the vertical centering didn't happen.

Comment: ok let me make a jsfiddle, also, can you provide the compiled HTML, not the framework code? For others... not for me

Comment: Ok, updated, You can pick whatever images you want for the jfiddle.

Comment: I made an edit (added fiddle), seems like adding parseFloat makes it work